# Is the dot product a projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection

Define $$\boldsymbol{\mu}=\frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}\boldsymbol{x_i}$$
If we have a direction vector $\boldsymbol{w}$, The book stated that the projection of the mean onto the line $\boldsymbol{w}$ is given by:
$$
m_k=\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{\mu}
$$

---

I don't get this. Isn't the projection of $\mu$ onto $w$ given by:
$$
\boldsymbol{m}=\boldsymbol{w}\frac{\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{\mu}}{||\boldsymbol{w}||}
$$
I've attached the part on the book:[image: pic]

Comment: Should the definition be $\mathbb{\mu}=\frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}\mathbb{x_i}$?